# ¿Por qué al hacer "less | grep" me dice "Coincidencia en el archivo binario (entrada estándar)"?

Tags: linux, regex, unix, grep, linux-mint

Tengo que hacer dos ejercicios que me traen dolor de cabeza, porque a algunos compañeros les ha salido con los comandos que voy a poner, pero a mi con el mismo nada... Hay que buscar en el archivo "Veinte.txt".

Primero: Muestra y cuenta las líneas de Veinte.txt que contengan primero la cadena "Nautilus” pero luego NO incluya "Nemo".

```
less Veinte.txt | grep "Nautilus" | grep -v -n "Nemo"
```

Me sale "Coincidencia en el archivo binario (entrada estándar)", lo mismo que:

Muestra y cuenta las líneas que contengan fechas relativas al siglo XIX (de 1800 a 1899):

```
less Veinte.txt | grep -n "18[00-99]"
```

Pero en ambas no me salen las líneas como tal. ¿Alguna idea de porqué puede ser?

[Este es](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EUVzo-HVoO4gnfL74uu-5Hm64gKEh9xf/view?usp=sharing) el txt que estoy usando. Este es un fragmento:

```
 -Señor, aunque haya roto usted con la humanidad, quiero creer que no ha renegado de todo sentimiento 
 humano. Somos náufragos, caritativamente recogidos a bordo de su barco, no lo olvidaremos. En cuanto a 
 mí, me doy cuenta de que si el interés de la ciencia pudiera absorber hasta la necesidad de la libertad, lo que 
 me promete nuestro encuentro me ofrecería grandes compensaciones.
 Pensaba yo que el comandante iba a tenderme la mano para sellar nuestro tratado, pero no lo hizo y lo 
 sentí por él.
 -Una última pregunta -dije en el momento en que ese ser inexplicable parecía querer retirarse.
 -Dígame, señor profesor.
 -¿Con qué nombre debo llamarle?
 -Señor -respondió el comandante-, yo no soy para ustedes más que el capitán Nemo, y sus compañeros y 
 usted no son para mí más que los pasajeros del Nautilus.
 El capitán Nemo llamó y apareció un steward. El capitán le dio unas órdenes en esa extraña lengua que 
 yo no podía reconocer. Luego, volviéndose hacia el canadiense y Conseil, dijo:
 -Les espera el almuerzo en su camarote. Tengan la amabilidad de seguir a este hombre.
 -No es cosa de despreciar -dijo el arponero, a la vez que salía, con Conseil, de la celda en la que 
 permanecíamos desde hacía más de treinta horas.
 -Y ahora, señor Aronnax, nuestro almuerzo está dispuesto. Permítame que le guíe.
 -A sus órdenes, capitán.
 Seguí al capitán Nemo, y nada más atravesar la puerta, nos adentramos por un estrecho corredor 
 iluminado eléctricamente. Tras un recorrido de una decena de metros, se abrió una segunda puerta ante mí.
 Entré en un comedor, decorado y amueblado con un gusto severo. En sus dos extremidades se elevaban 
 altos aparadores de roble con adornos incrustados de ébano, y sobre sus anaqueles en formas onduladas 
 brillaban cerámicas, porcelanas y cristalerías de un precio inestimable. Una vajiHa lisa resplandecía en 
 ellos bajo los rayos que emitía un techo luminoso cuyo resplandor mitigaban y tamizaban unas pinturas de 
 delicada factura y ejecución.
 En el centro de la sala había una mesa ricamente servida. El capitán Nemo me indicó el lugar en que 
 debía instalarme.
```

Answer (score 3):

El error indica que lo que le llega a `grep` no es "texto puro". `grep` supone que lo que le está llegando es un archivo binario, que puede contener cualquier byte, y por tanto evita volcarlo por la terminal pues el envío de ciertos bytes a la terminal podría "corromperla" (hacer que deje de mostrar texto correctamente). En ese caso, en lugar del texto hallado, simplemente emite un mensaje indicando que "encontró texto" pero no lo va a mostrar.

¿Por qué le llegan a `grep` bytes raros que le hacen creer que no se trata de texto estándar? Se me ocurren dos explicaciones:

1. Que has usado `less` para enviarle el texto. `less` es un comando diseñado para volcar un fichero a una terminal y no a otro programa. En particular, se detiene cada cierto número de líneas para darte oportunidad a leerlo todo, y cuando pulses espacio continuar. Además, la salida de `less` puede llevar insertados bytes especiales para decirle a la terminal que cambie el color del texto, para de ese modo mostrar los ficheros "coloreados" con ciertas reglas que puedan hacer más fácil su lectura. Estos bytes pueden estar confundiendo a `grep`

   No creo que esta sea la causa pues en principio `less` es capaz de detectar si se está usando para volcar a una terminal o para volcar a una tubería (`|`), y en el segundo caso cambia su comportamiento.

   De todas formas en lugar de `less` deberías usar `cat` para enviar un fichero a `grep`, por ejemplo así: `cat fichero | grep patron`. O ¿por qué no? usar la opción de `grep` para que sea éste quien lea el fichero directamente en vez de sacarlo de la tubería, por ejemplo: `grep patron fichero`.
2. Que el propio fichero tiene bytes raros en su interior. Si es éste el caso, la solución que acabo de proponerte con `cat` o directamente con `grep` seguiría dándote el mismo resultado.

Si a tus compañeros les funciona pero a ti no, la causa más probable es que esteis usando un fichero de entrada diferente. Aunque visualmente parezca el mismo, quizás el tuyo contiene bytes "raros" introducidos por un editor que hayas usado. Por ejemplo, si has abierto el archivo en Windows y lo has guardado antes de enviarlo a la máquina Linux, eso pudo haber añadido al fichero bytes con retornos de carro, una codificación inapropiada de los caracteres no-ascii, o una secuencia especial de bytes al inicio (llamada el BOM) que además es invisible en los editores.

### Actualización

**Confirmado**, el fichero `Veinte.txt` que has enlazado en Drive, tiene un formato erróneo para lo que grep espera. Por un lado, lleva las eñes y tildes codificadas en ISO-8859 y grep probablemente esté esperando UTF8. Eso le lleva a "creer" que el fichero no es de texto, y por tanto a tratarlo como binario.

Además, los finales de línea están marcados por "CR" (también llamado `\r`, valor 0D) en lugar de tener un "LF" (también llamado `\n`, valor 0A) como se espera en el mundo Unix. Esto llevaría a grep a "creer" que todo el fichero es una única línea.

Puedes arreglar ambos problemas así:

```
iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 Veinte.txt | tr '\r' '\n' > Veinte_arreglado.txt
```

(No intentes volcar el resultado al mismo fichero `Veinte.txt` o se borrará, pero puedes renombrar `Veinte_arreglado.txt` una vez obtenido)

Comment: Para convertir los saltos de línea, existen `dos2unix` y `unix2dos`. ¡Son muy útiles!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Si, pero en este caso el programa necesario sería `mac2unix`, ya que el formato "solo LF" es del mac (es ya un formato muy antiguo, hoy día siguen el estándar unix). En Windows se usa CRLF.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás primero leyendo el fichero con 'less' para posteriormente intentar hacer un Grep. Puede que funcione a tus compañeros, pero no es una manera demasiado ortodoxa de hacerlo. Además, sería útil mirar antes si el fichero es considerado como binario por parte del sistema.

Por ello, simplemente usa grep contra el archivo y ya está:

```
grep "Nautilus" fichero | grep -v -n "Nemo"

grep -n "18[00-99]" fichero
```

Si el archivo es binario y cuentas con GNU Grep, usa además el flag `-a` para procesarlo: `grep -an 'bla' fichero`.